# How to not insert a field in mongodb if it is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I don't want mongodb to create a date/time field, if i am passing a null value, the code below works for all non-date types but fails for the date type. It creates a date/time field with a null value instead. This is a code snippet of my bsondocument below

```
   {"stringfield", stringfield= string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringfield)?null:stringfield},
   {"datetime", datetime.HasValue == false ?null:datetime}
```

Note: I am not making use of any classes to map mongodb fields to properties, rather directly creating a bsondocument and inserting that document in mongodb.

I tried using the Convention pack with the following code below, but i guess that applies only when i create classes to map mongofields to properties?

```
        var pack = new ConventionPack();
        var ignoreIfNull = new IgnoreIfNullConvention(true);
        pack.Add(ignoreIfNull);
        ConventionRegistry.Register("ignoreNulls", pack, t => true);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43259080/194717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: As requested by people in the comments, i am including a proper answer to the solution with the link as a reference.

Below is the code snippet that sets the date field in a mongodb document if the nullbale 'mydate' parameter has a value, or simply does not create the field if its null or empty.

```
{ "date", mydate.Value, mydate.HasValue }
```

And below is the reference link that contains the answer from **@Craig Wilson** at the **mongodb-csharp** google group as i had posted this same question over there too.

[How to not insert a field in mongodb if it is null?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-csharp/cZvfGVp55Zo/p6ga_dISxO8J)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @jproffitt -  have updated the answer now as requested.

Comment: @AlphaMale - It does provide an answer to the question, the solution was described in the link, i am not requesting any clarification from the author here but providing a valid link to the solution that worked for me in a much efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to insert the field with a null value, don't insert it with a null value. Instead, don't put the field in the document at all. Meaning, instead of this:

```
db.stuff.insert({ "a" : 1, "b" : null })
```

do this

```
db.stuff.insert({ "a" : 1 })
```

It might not be a problem for you to insert null values of fields anyway, since they behave like missing values for queries:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "a" : 1 })
> db.test.insert({ "a" : 1, "b" : null })
> db.test.count({ "b" : null })
2
```

Comment: I actually didnt want to insert any null values as i didnt want mongo to store any fields that are empty, taking advantage of its dynamic schema. Well, i have exactly done the way you mentioned about not inserting the field at all, i had to add an extra if - else with blocks of code containing only the required fields based on the condition. Thanks for the help!!