# Do not insert field if null or empty

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a C# class with some fields and some of them are null. Those that are null I do not want to be inserted into db with null value. I do not want them inserted into db at all.
How do I achieve that?

```
class User
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public string MidName;
}
```

Not every user has a MidName, but Mongo inserts into db with null value on MidName field.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using the aptly named [`[BsonIgnoreIfNull]` attribute](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/2.2/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_Attributes_BsonIgnoreIfNullAttribute.htm):

```
class User
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string MidName;
}
```

Comment: Hi, that works when type is string. How about double? [BsonIgnoreIfNull] is not working then.

Comment: Then you use [`[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/1.5/html/6c70ebcd-7b01-e2f4-47db-38459f35f1d9.htm).

Comment: Be wary of this people https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1678

Answer (score 12):

Ensure you are registering the new convention pack early enough. If any classes have already been mapped before you register the new convention pack they won't be updated.

Here's my test code:

```
public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string S { get; set; }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConventionRegistry.Register(
            "Ignore null values",
            new ConventionPack
            {
                new IgnoreIfNullConvention(true)
            },
            t => true);

        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<C>("test");

        collection.Drop();
        collection.Insert(new C { Id = 1, S = null });

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The following document was inserted into the database:

> db.test.find()

```
{ "_id" : 1 }
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/7-NFXBNeEXs

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with to prevent the insertion of Null & Empty values was by creating a custom `Attribute` that inherits the [`IBsonMemberMapAttribute`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_IBsonMemberMapAttribute.htm) interface and uses the [`BsonMemberMap.SetShouldSerializeMethod()`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_BsonMemberMap_SetShouldSerializeMethod.htm) method. Both come from the `MongoDB.Bson.Serialization` namespace which comes from the [MongoDb.Driver Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver).

**Step 1:** Create the Custom Attribute

```
// BsonIgnoreIfNullOrEmptyAttribute.cs
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using System.Collections;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class BsonIgnoreIfNullOrEmptyAttribute : Attribute, IBsonMemberMapAttribute
{

  public void Apply(BsonMemberMap memberMap)
  {
     _ = memberMap.SetShouldSerializeMethod(classObj =>
     {
        string propertyName = memberMap.MemberName;
        var propertyValue = classObj?.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(classObj);

        return propertyValue switch
        {
            null => false,
            string value when string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) => false,
            ICollection collection when collection.Count == 0 => false,
            _ => true
        };
     });
  }

}
```

**Explanation:** Inside the `Apply()` method, I used `memberMap.MemberName` which gives you the `propertyName` of the property that has the `[BsonIgnoreIfNullOrEmpty] Attribute` and then I used reflections to get the value of that property when it is read by the MongoDB's [`IBsonSerializer`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/apidocs/html/Methods_T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_IBsonSerializer.htm) (which is determined by the [`BsonClassMap`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/apidocs/html/Methods_T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_BsonClassMap.htm)). Next, I created a switch expression that will validate the value of the property and check if the value is null or empty for `string` and `ICollection` types.
**Note:** Returning `false` inside the `SetShouldSerializeMethod() method` means that it will NOT serialize the property.

---

**Step 2:** Use the Custom Attribute on the desired properties.

It will behavior similarly to the other [`[BsonIgnore...]`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/apidocs/html/N_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_Attributes.htm) `Attributes`

```
// User.cs
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

public class User
{
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNullOrEmpty]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNullOrEmpty]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNullOrEmpty]
    public string MidName { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public Department Department  { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNullOrEmpty]
    public IEnumerable<Guid> FriendIds { get; set; }
}
```