# How to ignore null values globally by calling obj.ToBsonDocument() using MongoDB C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

**Prehistory**: I have a class hierarchy (a big one) which was  generated from an XML schema (XSD).

```
MyObj obj;
```

**Nowadays**: I need to parse a string value, which is actually an XML to an object using the generated class hierarchy and then I need to put the object into MongoDB.  The code is:

```
private BsonDocument XmlToBson(string content)
{
    MyObj obj;
    using (var reader = new StringReader(content))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObj));
        obj = (MyObj) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    return obj.ToBsonDocument();
}
```

**The problem**: I have a lot of null children objects in the hierarchy, it looks like this in Robomongo:

[image: Object which is null is added]

I want to avoid adding null objects into the database. I know I can ignore them one by one, like described here [Ignoring Default Values](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/#ignoring-default-values) by using attributes or lambda expressions. But because the hierarchy is big and complex I do not like this approach. I am to lazy to list all the properties which have to be ignored when they have null values. Even more, the class can be regenerated in future and it will be a nightmare to support the list of properties which have to be ignored.

**Question**: How can I achieve the goal and ignore the null values globally no matter where the object is in hierarchy? I am working with MongoDB C# driver ver. 2.2.

Comment: Hey Antipod, ignoring them will be difficult if they exist and you're not removing them by a `null` value check. What do you mean by "ignore" btw, as in not insert them or insert another object if it's null into the column as a "placeholder"?

Comment: By "ignore" I mean I do not want to see them in the database. Put fake values, i.e. values which will not be used, does not sound as a good idea, I do not want to have trash in the database. And checking if something is null (how?) and remove it sounds like an overhead or probably I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43259080/194717

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can apply the effects of most attributes to all properties while serializing by registering convention packs.

Below the `IgnoreIfNullConvention` is registered, implicitly applying the `[IgnoreIfNull]` attribute to all properties while serializing and deserializing.

```
var anon = new
{
    Foo = "bar",
    Baz = (string)null,
};

ConventionRegistry.Register("Ignore", 
                            new ConventionPack 
                            { 
                                new IgnoreIfNullConvention(true) 
                            }, 
                            t => true);

var bsonDocument = anon.ToBsonDocument();
```

This will yield a document only containing the `Foo` key.

When desired, you can also `Remove()` this convention pack by name after serialization.

Comment: This is very elegant, wish I'd known about this for a long time!

Answer (score 6):

You can also apply the `[BsonIgnoreIfNull]` attribute from the *MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes*
namespace to a class field if you don't what that field with a null value to appear in the BSON Document.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public List<string> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually, using `IgnoreIfDefaultConvention` can cause an unintended behavior due the fact it affects **all** *default values*. For instance, values as the list above will not be saved:

- *int* = 0
- *decimal* = 0
- *bool* = false

If you want to ignore only **null values**, the best approach is `IgnoreIfNullConvention`.

Here is an example of it:

```
ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreIfNullConvention", new ConventionPack { new IgnoreIfNullConvention(true) }, t => true);
```

Comment: this brings another problem, what if we need to ignore empty arrays and null values but not the int decimal bool?